# How many hours does Carson Daly spend on "Last Call w/ Carson Daly?

Tags: last-call-with-carson-daly

He obviously lives in New York so he can be on the Today Show. But most, if not all, of Carson Last Call interviews are taken place on the West Coast/Hollywood. Not to mention the stage acts.

Does anyone know how much time Carson Daly spends on that show? It seems kind of a softball to me that he does essentially nothing on that show except his name. PLEASE tell me I'm wrong. I rather like the guy.

Answer (score 1):

Since September 2013 Daly isn't involved much. [As explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Call_with_Carson_Daly):

> It was eventually decided that **Daly would limit his role on *Last Call*
>   to the opening and closing segments as of the 13th season**. All other
>   segments are either interviews done by producers or production
>   assistants without comment by them, or straight musical performances
>   with only Daly's continuity introducing them.